# What is -ms-touch-action called in other browsers?

Tags: css, pointer-events

What is the equivalent to [`-ms-touch-action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767313.aspx) for other browsers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is now a non-prefixed `touch-action` property, proposed in the [W3C Pointer Events Candidate recomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/).

From the [MSDN documentation linked to in the OP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767313.aspx):

> As of Internet Explorer 11, the Microsoft vendor prefixed version of this event (`-ms-touch-action`) is no longer supported and may be removed in a future release. Instead, use the non-prefixed name `touch-action`, which is better for standards compliance and future compatibility.

Comment: From Google Chrome what is the value please? (show example its not helping) i have issues in windows 8.1 pro with many touch screens.

Comment: @YumYumYum You should be able to use `touch-action` in Chrome, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-touch-action. If you are having a specific issue with this property, perhaps you could possible a minimal sample which reproduces your issue as a new question.

Comment: I used touch-action. But in Ello touch screen and iiyama touch screen mouse cursor moves but when i apply touch it does not trigger click. touch-action is working in HP All in one touch screens with same Javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one. It's [part of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453816.aspx) IE10's features for supporting custom multi-touch interactions or gestures.

Take a look at this [overview](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) of the implemented, prefixed CSS properties, and their counterparts in other web browser engines.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is shipping touch-action support in Chrome 35 (now in beta): http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/chrome-35-beta-more-developer-control.html