# -ms-touch-action equivalent for other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, touch

In order to make touch screen friendly website IE supports

```
canvas {
    -ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom;
}
```

Is there any equivalent to be used with other browsers like chrome, Firefox, opera and safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is -ms-touch-action called in other browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255727/what-is-ms-touch-action-called-in-other-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way of implementing this in other browsers, see Krazers answer to this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291359/1977007

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is shipping support for touch-action in Chrome 35: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/chrome-35-beta-more-developer-control.html